# Como pegar o retorno do método doInBackground no android?

Tags: android, asynctask

Estou começando a trabalhar com AsyncTasks e ainda não sei muita coisa. Criei uma classe que estende AsyncTask e implementei o método `doInBackground()`, mas minha dúvida agora é saber como eu obtenho o retorno desse método?
Em outra classe no método `efetuarLogin()` , eu faço uma chamada para o método `execute()` , mas ele não me retorna a String que deveria retornar.
Como posso obter o retorno do método doInBackground?
Agradeço desde já a colaboração de todos!

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String resposta = "";

    try {
        resposta = this.sendGet(params[0]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return resposta;
}
```

Método que chama a classe que estende da AsyncTask:

```
public Usuario efetuarLogin(String email, String senha){

    JSONStringer js = new JSONStringer();
    ConexaoHttp conexao = new ConexaoHttp();

    try {
        js.object();
        js.key("email").value(email);
        js.key("senha").value(senha);
        js.endObject();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String usuario = conexao.execute(js.toString()); // não retorna uma String, dá erro dizendo que ele retorna um objeto do tipo AsyncTask

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se ainda estiver enfrentando esse problema, uma sugestão que eu usei faz algum tempo é usar o método `get()` do objeto instanciado com a classe que herda da AsyncTask logo após invocar o método `execute()`. Confesso que não sei dizer se é a maneira mais adequada, mas acredito que no momento, possa resolver seu problema.
Dessa forma seu código ficaria assim:

```
public Usuario efetuarLogin(String email, String senha){

    JSONStringer js = new JSONStringer();
    ConexaoHttp conexao = new ConexaoHttp();

    try {
        js.object();
        js.key("email").value(email);
        js.key("senha").value(senha);
        js.endObject();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    conexao.execute(js.toString());
    String retorno = conexao.get(); // esse método retorna a resposta do método doInBackground()

    return retorno;
}
```

Comment: Assim você está a usar o AsyncTask de forma síncrona. O método get() do AsyncTask só retorna quando o método doInBackground() terminar.

Answer (score 2):

O método `doInBackground` passa o resultado para outro método do AsyncTask, o `onPostExecute`.

No seu caso, se o Asynctask estiver criado na própria Activity, você poderia atribuir o valor de `usuario` dentro dele:

```
void onPostExecute(String result) {
     usuario = result;
 }
```

O método `execute` em si não retorna nada. O ideal é colocar o restante do código que você irá usar com esse usuário também no método acima, pois o Asynctask roda em Background e a thread principal só sabe que ele terminou por esse método.

Mais detalhes sobre Asynctask, você pode ver aqui:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html